# How do I show the selected items in an easier manner in this dropdown

Tags: usability, usability-testing, checkboxes, dropdown, drop-down-list

I have a dropdown with checkboxes as items. [HERE](https://codepen.io/zupkode/pen/JwJBKw) is the working example

[image]

I let people select multiple options from this after they search for it
One problem I notice is that it is not immediately obvious which items have been selected. 
[image]

1. Should I add a button that says show selected, how does filtering work with that?
2. Should I add a checkbox saying show selected, what happens during filtering?
3. Should I add tags below this searchbox where each tag has a delete button and shows the selected item?
4. Here is another way to rephrase the question, what is the easiest way the user will see their selected options in this?

Some guidance is super appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some alternatives:

**Filter Tags**: No need for users to click to expand the dropdown. They can see which ones are applied and remove them if wanted.

[image]

**Summary of Selected Filters**: Group selected options in a specific section towards the top, while repeating them in your list.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, based on your inputs, I have made a new version of the widget here https://codepen.io/zupkode/pen/EGvgvx Feel free to suggest improvements :) merry xmas

Comment: @PirateApp - I would keep the tags on the left and move the checkbox list to the right, this way the list doesn't jump position every time I select a new checkbox (which is annoying). Also, if the intention is to list all the selected filters in the bottom with "You selected...", then you should simply pull out all the tags and place them outside the dropdown. The common pattern (most ecommerce sites) is having the tags places close to the filter dropdown so the user can make the association that one affect the other.